# Azure stack - Is it possible to have azure data lake gen 1 on premises?

Tags: azure, azure-stack

Evaluating the azure stack on premises  for hybrid cloud use case. Is it possible to configure azure data lake store on premises and big data analytic software getting connected with out need of having the data in cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Data Lake is not available in Azure Stack.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13491624-azure-stack-support

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/344565-azure-stack/suggestions/32931043-bring-hdinsight-datalake-store-and-other-advance

All of the feedback that you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Azure Stack team.

We appreciate your time and interest in Azure Stack.

If you experience any issues with the ASDK, feel free to [contact us](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=AzureStack).